# Is it bad practice to store obsolete authorized_keys as user/group nobody?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I'm using Chef to manage users on a cluster of servers. When a user is removed I'm keeping their authorized_keys file and changing the file's user/group to "nobody" after deleting the relevant user from the server. Is it bad practice to do this?

Edit:
I'm running CentOS 5 on my cluster.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authorized_keys` file contains public keys, which wouldn't do any harm if they fell into some attacker's hands, they're meant to be public.